# Is it possible for SSL to check certificate hostname against "host" HTTP header instead of URL?

Tags: tls

This is bit of a follow up question for [SSL verification of host name of https server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6359/ssl-verification-of-host-name-of-https-server)

I'm trying to request a page through HTTPS directly from an IP rather than a hostname. Concerning the answers to the question above I understand why the certificate is based on hostname rather than IP. However, I still want to request the page directly from the IP rather than a hostname, basically bypassing the DNS lookup.

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to avoid validating the certificate. Obviously not the most secure method. Is there a way instead to have SSL check the certificate against the hostname (known to the client) while still requesting an IP directly?

Comment: What client software do you use for requesting your page ?

Comment: if you already know the hostname, why not request with the hostname?

Comment: This does not make any sense: the servers certificate is checked by the client. The HTTP Host header is included by the client in the request to the server. Therefore the client must know the hostname already. Apart from that the client is validating the server certificate and not the server is validating its own certificate based on the Host header sent by the client. I'm voting to close this question because it is too unclear.

Comment: May you explain why you will request it by ip, not by hostname?

To make the validation possible, the client would need to know the hostname. Why would it not be used?

Comment: @binarym right now I'm using Python and specifically the Tornado framework

Comment: Yes the client knows the hostname, however I want to bypass the DNS lookup and query the desired IP directly. @Steffen, my last question is a suggestion to a possible solution. I'm not a networking/security expert, and the inherent noobishness of the question (which you pointed out) may have made my problem definition unclear. I will edit it out, and hopefully there won't be need to close.

Comment: @JadS: I think that I know understand the real problem.

Comment: You've stated that you want to bypass the DNS request, but not *why*.  Is this some ill-conceived attempt at a performance gain?

Comment: @Xiong performance gains definitely plays a part. Why "ill-conceived"?

Comment: Bypassing DNS gains you 1 or 2 ms on an network call.  In return, you lose flexibility, several load-balancing options, and the ability to fail over, you break the operator's ability to make changes to their infrastructure, and you open yourself up to all sorts of unexpected problems, like this one.  There are almost certainly other changes that will have fewer downsides and make much more of a difference.

Comment: @Xiong Those are some fair points. Though this solution still suits my current needs, I'll keep them in mind in the future.

Comment: It take assumption that you want to bypass DNS for developing purposes. Why don't you simply do it throught /etc/hosts (or its windows/mac os x equivalent) ? You'll have your whole network chain "coherent" and SSL should work as you wish out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing a HTTPS connection to some site is basically done this way:

1. get the IP address for the target hostname by using DNS
2. connect with TCP to this IP address
3. do the SSL handshake over this TCP connection, which includes

   1. optionally include the target hostname with the [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension in the start of the handshake (ClientHello). This is needed if multiple servers with different certificates share the same IP address and port.
   2. verify the certificate received from the server within the handshake to see if it is trusted and also if it is valid for the target hostname
4. once the SSL handshake is done send the HTTP request inside this SSL connection, which includes among other things the Host header

What you effectively want is to skip the DNS lookup (step 1) because you already know the IP address of the target. You still need to all the other steps, notably  3.1 (SNI) and 3.2 (validation of hostname inside certificate).

This is possible but how this is done depends on your programming language and libraries. Most languages make only the common case easy for you (i.e. connect by hostname) and uncommon cases like yours are more complex to implement. For example in Perl you could simply use the following code to connect to a site by IP address, but include the proper SNI extension for the target hostname and also check the certificate against the hostname:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL 1.971;
my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    PeerAddr => '1.2.3.4:443',
    SSL_hostname => 'www.example.com'
);
```

How this is done in the language of your choice is off-topic here and on-topic at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: if all they want is to avoid the DNS lookup, they should just put the hostname and hardcoded IP address in `/etc/hosts` and use the regular application as usual.

Comment: @Z.T. that's also a potential solution. However for configuration and to keep the system dynamic w.r.t. the IP/Hosts that it needs to handle, I'd rather try to solve the issue directly within the code.

Comment: @Z.T.: your solution works only when the user has the permissions to modify such system settings.

Comment: In python, was able to include the proper SNI using the `server_hostname` kwarg of the `ssl.SSLContext` object : `sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname)`

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are issued for Fully Qualified Domain Names and not IP addresses. You cannot change the logic to just validate the Host: header. However you can always ignore the error which is `'Common Name doesn't match FQDN'`